# Open Testing issues for compatible devices

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

There are no supported devices available when we publish app for Open testing in Play store. Should we first publish live and then do Open testing?

We wanted to have Open testing before launching the app for everyone. However, no android devices were listed as compatible. We have ensured minimum and maximum android versions are available